# Weightage search in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, nosql-aggregation

Is there a way I can add weight-age to specific fields in Mongo-db without indexing?

Document Format:

```
{
    "_id" : "55b3551164518e48",
    "item" : "Item A",
    "price": 400,
    "added_date": "2015-07-22",
    "seller": "Seller A"
},{
    "_id" : "55b3551164518e49",
    "item" : "Item A",
    "price": 200,
    "added_date":"2015-06-21",
    "seller": "Seller B"
}
```

In a document like the one above, the find query should be working based on priority in the following order:

1. Item name
2. Price(lowest)
3. Added Date(Latest)

Find query with "Item A" should be working in a way to return the second entry first as it is the one with lower price although the first entry is latest. Is there a way to add weightage(importance) to field in search query without indexing.

I am looking for a weightage field search like in

```
db.blog.createIndex( 
    { 
        content: "text", 
        keywords: "text", 
        about: "text" 
    }, 
    { 
        weights: { 
            content: 10, 
            keywords: 5 
        }, 
        name: "TextIndex" 
     } 
)
```

but without creating the index.

Comment: Why sorting by price and date doesn't work for you?

Comment: I think if you apply sorting by first "item" then "price" and finally by "added_date", it might work for you

Comment: `db.blog.createIndex(
   {
     content: "text",
     keywords: "text",
     about: "text"
   },
   {
     weights: {
       content: 10,
       keywords: 5
     },
     name: "TextIndex"
   }
 )`

I was looking for a weightage field search as like above without having to index.

Comment: @AkashSPrakash, please update the question instead of commenting on it. Do you realise the "weighted search" is a full-text index, and the weight matter only when you sort by relevance? To answer the exact wording of the question - no, weights is a part of the index and do not exists alone. I believe the question is a typical XY problem. If you try to rephrase it to ask what you really need, you may have better answers.

Answer (score 0):

Use the aggregation framwork to compute your data and sort them in term of your needs

Answer (score 0):

Use the following:

```
db.example.aggregate([
    $sort: {item: 1, price: -1, added_date: 1},
    $group: {_id: "$item", price: {$first: "$price"}, added_date: {$first: "$added_date"}}
]);
```

The fields required after grouping will need to added individually, and can be done using a similar syntax as `price: {$first: "$price"}`. Although creating an index is a more optimized way.

Comment: `db.blog.createIndex(
   {
     content: "text",
     keywords: "text",
     about: "text"
   },
   {
     weights: {
       content: 10,
       keywords: 5
  
   },
     name: "TextIndex"
   }
 )`

I was looking for a weightage field search as like above without having to index.

Comment: @AkashSPrakash The question specifically says without creating an index.